# No PropertyChanged option for UpdateSourceTrigger in Windows Phone 8 apps?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, textbox, mvvm-light, inotifypropertychanged

I have a Windows phone app with a *TextBox* two-way bound to a string property in my *ViewModel*, and on the same page a *Button* bound to an MVVM Light *RelayCommand* property in the *ViewModel*.  The relay command's *CanExecute* method checks to see if the *TextBox* is empty and if it is, returns FALSE.  Otherwise it returns TRUE so the user only presses the button after they have entered some text.

The problem is that I needed it to generate property changed notifications on every keystroke, not just when the *TextBox* lost focus.  I did some reading and the way to do that is to set the *UpdateSourceTrigger* on the *TextBox* to *PropertyChanged*.  However, in **Windows Phone 8** it appears that enum value is not supported, only *Default* and *Explicit*.  I double-checked this both in the *XAML editor* and in the *Create Data Binding* editor.  Because of this I was forced to use the *Explicit* option and now have to call the following code in the TextBox *TextChanged* event handler as per the *MSDN* docs:

```
    private void txtInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingExpression be = txtInput.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        be.UpdateSource();
    }
```

Where did the *Propertychanged* option go in Windows Phone 8?  Am I just doing something wrong?  Obviously I'd like to avoid doing this extra plumbing every time I want this behavior with a *TextBox*.  I'm fine with writing a derived *TextBox* control to get this behavior but if I don't have to I'd like to know of course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why data binding is not working with PropertyChanged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965338/why-data-binding-is-not-working-with-propertychanged)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone is based on Silverlight, not WPF. And Silverlight is kind of subset of WPF, or better to say [Silverlight is slimmer than WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750802/is-silverlight-a-subset-of-wpf). So it is not surprising to see something in WPF that is not available in Windows Phone, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is one example among other missing features ([another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233072/windowsphone-relativesource-mode-findancestor-ancestortype-cannotresolve-sy)).

So, unfortunately, you seems have to go with your current approach.

For Reference : [MSDN : WPF Features Not in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#wpf_features_not_in_silverlight)